# How to get events from json feed based on datepicker selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, fullcalendar

I'm using fullcalendar to show events from a mysql database.  The events are rendered in my events.php page and fullcalendar displays a json feed from events.php.  I'm trying to create a report/form submission page which will display the same information as fullcalendar for a specific day.

The problem is I don't seem to be requesting the date correctly because It gives me the exact same data regardless of what date I choose.  Eventually I'll be using a datepicker on the page to select the date, but for now I'm just trying to manually insert the date in the code.  No matter what date I choose it gives me the same result.  This is the script I'm using to request the data from events.php

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('#datepicker_1').change(function(){
        jQuery.post('events.php', 'view=person&start=2014-12-07'+'&end=2014-12-08', function(data){
            alert(data[0].id);

            });     
    });
});
</script>
```

Currently it gives me the exact same data no matter what date I choose.

Comment: You are not selecting the selected date for the query.  Please share html code as suggestion about how to select the date can be made. You can get the value of date by $(element).val()

Comment: I'm not sure what you're saying.  Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you never changed the parameter for start `start=2014-12-07` and end `&end=2014-12-08` paramater.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('#datepicker_1').change(function(){
        jQuery.post('events.php', 'view=person&start=2014-12-07'+'&end=2014-12-08', function(data){
            alert(data[0].id);

            });     
    });
});
</script>
```

Basing from the URL you have provided, the events.php accepts a date range and not just a date. Presuming you're just picking a date for the 'end' parameter and subtracting it by a day for the 'start' parameter you can just use this pseudocode here.

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
    dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
    onSelect: function(strDate){
        //Instantiate endDate from strDate

        //Assign a value to startDate by subtracting a day from endDate

        //Preformat post data from endDate and startDate

        //Send an ajax call using the preformatted data and handle the response
    }
});
```

Hopefully this helps

Comment: I get the idea of what you're saying, but I'm not sure how to do this part

     //Instantiate endDate from strDate

        //Assign a value to startDate by subtracting a day from endDate

        //Preformat post data from endDate and startDate

        //Send an ajax call using the preformatted data and handle     the response